# How to wipe my iPhone that's stuck in the update process?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I've got an iPhone that is not locked down via the cloud, just PIN.  Unfortunately, the PIN has been lost.  I did the home button down, plug into the computer thing to get it to attach.  I then tried to do the wipe from the computer, but it said the software had to be updated first.  After allowing the update process to go along for awhile the phone rebooted.  It's now at a "swipe to update" screen.  If I swipe, it asks for the PIN (which I don't have).  I'm unable to power it off now (it doesn't respond to the power button).  Attaching it to the computer just gives the backup (PIN required) screen, no wipe option available.

Is there any way to recover from this point?  Is it worth trying to run down the battery to kill it and then try again?  Even if I do, how can I do a wipe without getting stuck in the same place again?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

Comment: @Tyson If you could make that an answer, I'll accept it.  I was trying to power off the normal way instead of a hard poweroff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263

"Press and hold both the Sleep/Wake and Home button for at least 10 seconds, and don't release when you see the Apple logo. Keep holding until you see the recovery mode screen."